# npm install jquery fails on node-gyp rebuild

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

I can't seem to get jquery to install on the latest release of npm/node.  Here's the stack trace:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser/1.7.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/location/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/navigator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/location/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser/1.7.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/navigator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> contextify@0.1.3 install /root/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.commands.forEach.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:56:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:185:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:105:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:534:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:634:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stdin (child_process.js:806:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:356:10)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-24-server
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.9.1-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing contextify@0.1.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't seem to get jquery to install on the latest release of npm/node.

The latest releases of Node.JS are [v0.8.8 (stable)](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/v0.8.8) ([release notes](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/08/22/node-v0-8-8-stable/), [download](http://nodejs.org/download/)) and [v0.9.0 (unstable)](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/v0.9.0).

What you're currently running is `v0.9.1-pre` -- a development build from the work being done towards a `v0.9.1` release.

And, that's the problem:

> Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed

The modules you're attempting to install don't support running on a development build. So, you'll have to decide on a release version to try them with.

You may also want to make note of the [versioning scheme](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ) that Node.JS uses.

Comment: weird I am having the problems with gyp while trying to install jquery on node 0.8.6 stable? `gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make`…`gyp ERR! stack at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)`

Comment: Hmmm, just did a clean install with node 0.8.8 and it worked fine now… must have been some kind of conlict :)

Comment: Weird...I was convinced I was on 0.8.x. Thx!